# Android 10 system dialog for wifi connection title is always english

Tags: android, xamarin, dialog, wifi

since Android 10, we have to suggest or specify networks to which the users can connect.

With Xamarin Forms I specify a network the following way:

```
           var specifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
               .SetSsid("MY_WIFI")
               .Build();

            var request = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .AddTransportType(TransportType.Wifi) // we want WiFi
                .RemoveCapability(NetCapability.Trusted)
                .RemoveCapability(NetCapability.WifiP2p)
                .SetNetworkSpecifier(specifier) // we want _our_ network
                .Build();

            connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(request, _callback);
```

Then the system dialog from Android opens and suggests the network. The user has to touch it, to connect it.
The dialog title is "Devices to use with APP_NAME"

My question is if we can change the "Devices to use with" part. Because we are a german company and the smartphone system language is also german. It would be nice to translate it by ourself if the system does not do it by itself.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi , could you share a screenshot ? I will check that whether can be modified .

Comment: I edit my Question. the pink area is of course not normally pink. I only used it to disguise it. The buttons are in german language but not the title. that is not really nice

Answer (score 0):

I have found no way to change that in application ,however it can be updated by system language .

If changing the system language to **Deutsch** ,

[image]

then this dialog will show **Deutsch** as follow :

[image]

Comment: But my phone is in german system language since i bought it as a new device. Please see my question. i update it with a new image. Maybe it is in english because its a debug version? Maybe the text is in german as soon as i upload it as a release version?

Comment: @XXXMysteriXXX Okey , it's strange ! I tested in simulator and it works , becuause my phone can not set Deutsch . Which device you tested ?

Comment: Its a Samsung Galaxy S10 with Android 10. The behavior, you see is exactly, what i also want to see. Unfortunatly its the only device with Android 10, i own. So i can not test it on other Devices.

Comment: @XXXMysteriXXX Maybe other devices will work . If so this should be modified by Samsung . Now also only having a XiaoMi 9 devive and my time zone can not set Deutsch lauguage .Later if have other devices to test this , will update here .